# Confirm these 301 redirects are correctly setup in my htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, https, redirect, http, html

i have in my root directory my english page and in subdirectory folder arabic page but the rule but as per  https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arianamedicaretour\.com$ [NC]
```

This condition was not met.

8

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.arianamedicaretour.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

This rule was not met.

9

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

This condition was not met.

10

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

This rule was not met.

11

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arianamedicaretour\.com$ [NC]
```

This condition was not met.

12

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ar/(.*)$ [NC]
```

This condition was not met.

13

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.arianamedicaretour.com/ar/%1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

This rule was not met. thats why the ar pages not redirecting. kindly Confirm what is correct condition for subdirectory 301 redirects in my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Pass through the Authorization header to the environment.
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Set the base URL for per-directory rewrites.
RewriteBase /


# If the requested resource does not correspond to a real file or directory,
# rewrite requests to /index.html (used commonly in single-page applications).
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

# Redirect non-www to www with HTTPS for the entire site, including the "ar" subdirectory.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arianamedicaretour\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.arianamedicaretour.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Ensure all requests are served over HTTPS.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Specific rule for the "ar" subdirectory to ensure it's also affected by the redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arianamedicaretour\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ar/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.arianamedicaretour.com/ar/%1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please format console output / settings / commands   as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That retains formatting, indentation and avoids Markdown mishaps,  as well as improves readability and attracts better answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About mod\_rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)